# Map Annotation Won't Show Custom UIButton for rightCalloutAccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a map with dozens of annotations. The annotations correctly show title and subtitle and I would like to add a custom "Go" button to the right of them. The Go button will open Apple Maps and give users directions to the annotation they were looking at on the map.

I've copied the code I'm using below. In it's current form, no button will appear.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if !(annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        let pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: String(annotation.hash))

        let rightButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        rightButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Go"), for: .normal)
        rightButton.tag = annotation.hash

        pinView.canShowCallout = true
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton

        return pinView
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

If I remove the following line:

```
rightButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Go"), for: .normal)
```

and change the one above it to:

```
let rightButton = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
```

The button does correctly display, which tells me that it's a problem with my attempt to use a custom image for the button.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to correct it by changing the UIButton type to the following:

```
let rightButton = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
```

My code snippet now looks so:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if !(annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        let pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: String(annotation.hash))

        let rightButton = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
        rightButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Go"), for: .normal)
        rightButton.tag = annotation.hash

        pinView.canShowCallout = true
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton

        return pinView
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```